# Unable to verify response from server using Sockets in android

Tags: android, sockets

I am working on an android chat application based on sockets. I am using the following code to implement this:

1. NetClient.java

   ```
   public class NetClient {

   /**
    * Maximum size of buffer
    */
   public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
   private Socket socket = null;
   private PrintWriter out = null;
   private BufferedReader in = null;

   private String host = null;
   private int port = 3000;
   // private int port;


   /**
    * Constructor with Host, Port
    *
    * @param host
    * @param port
    */
   public NetClient(String host, int port) {
       this.host = host;
       this.port = port;
   }

   private void connectWithServer() {
       Log.e("Server", "Connecting with server");
       try {
           if (socket == null) {
               System.out.println("Socket is null");
               socket = new Socket(this.host, this.port);
               out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
               in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
           }
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   private void disConnectWithServer() {
       Log.e("Server", "Disconnecting with server");
       if (socket != null) {
           if (socket.isConnected()) {
               try {
                   in.close();
                   out.close();
                   socket.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }
   }

   public void sendDataWithString(String message) {
       Log.e("Send data", "Sendind data to server");
       if (message != null) {
           connectWithServer();
           out.write(message);
           out.flush();
       }
   }

   public String receiveDataFromServer() {
       Log.e("Receive data", "Receivind data from the server");
       try {
           String message = "";
           int charsRead = 0;
           char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];

           while ((charsRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
               message += new String(buffer).substring(0, charsRead);

           }
           //Log.e("ServerResponse", message);
           disConnectWithServer(); // disconnect server
           return message;
       } catch (IOException e) {
           return "Error receiving response:  " + e.getMessage();
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. ChatActivity.java

   ```
   public class ChatActivity extends Activity {

   private EditText edtMsg;

   private Button btnSend;

   private String serverIpAddress = "192.168.2.250";
   private int port = 3000;

   private boolean connected = false;

   private Handler handler = new Handler();
   private BufferedReader in = null;
   private PrintWriter out = null;
   public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048; // Max. size of buffer
   private Socket socket = null;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
       edtMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMessage);
       btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendMessage);
       btnSend.setOnClickListener(connectListener);
   }

   private View.OnClickListener connectListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Log.e("Button", "Button clicked");
           if (!connected) {
               if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                   Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                   cThread.start();
               }
           }
       }
   };

   public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

       public void run() {

           NetClient nc = new NetClient(serverIpAddress, port);
           String message = edtMsg.getText().toString().trim();
           Log.e("Msg", message);
           nc.sendDataWithString(message);
           String response = nc.receiveDataFromServer();
           Log.e("Server Response ", response);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

I am not able to verify whether the data has been posted to server or not as i am getting unexpected result from the server.

3. Logcat

   E/Server Response﹕ [ 12-01 14:56:01.313   302: 1017 V/qcbassboost ]

I think i am doing some mistake in the use of socket.Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: If that server is sending you that data, everything is working perfectly except that you're probably sending it the wrong stuff.

Comment: @EJP This response is what i am getting according to my code.Do you think ,i have done anything wrong in my code?Please suggest me the changes .

Comment: I think your code is working perfectly, and I've already said so. I think you're sending the wrong *data*, and I've already said that too. Or else you're *expecting* the wrong data.

Comment: k. Thanks EJP. I will check it .